# Why changing flex direction changes the child height?

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to make a media query to display an input below the other instead on your side using Flexbox. As you can see, with my current code, I'm getting this:

[image]

But if I change the `flex-direction` to `column`, the input width is not the original. This is the result:

[image]

This is the my HTML:

```
<div id="mc_embed_signup">
  <form action="//eliasgarcia.us8.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=55cf7078733f0b62eb97733e3&amp;id=ace40b1824" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
    <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
      <label for="mce-EMAIL">No te pierdas ningún artículo</label>
      <div class="mc-wrapper">
        <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="Correo electrónico" required>
        <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
        <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true">
          <input type="text" name="b_55cf7078733f0b62eb97733e3_ace40b1824" tabindex="1" value="">
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="submit" value="Suscríbete" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="mc-error">
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

And this is my CSS:

```
#mc_embed_signup {
  label {
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .mc-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 30px 0px 0px 0px;
  }
  #mce-EMAIL {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px 30px 0px 0px;
    border: 2px solid $medium-grey;
    border-radius: 4px;
    text-indent: 20px;
  }
  .button {
    margin: 0px auto;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
}
```

Why is this happening?

NOTE: I can't provide a Fiddle because this is an integration with MailChip, so it calls a JS Script and it's not working properly on Fiddle, I don't know why... But the script doesn't add any extra classes, only the ones above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The flex children of a flex parent with `flex-direction: row` (the default for `display: flex`) will be equal heights. So since your left `input` is a direct child of `.mc-wrapper`, it's height will be equal to the height of the item beside it, and that will cause the `input`'s height to grow since the flex child on the right is taller.

When you switch to a `flex-direction: column` you no longer have adjacent children in a row, and flexbox will not try to match the heights, so the `input` will be whatever height it is naturally.

Comment: Ahhh, I understand it now! So, in this case, there is no possibility to set the first input height the same as the second right?

Comment: @EliasGarcia not without modifying your markup. But it's easy - just wrap the `input` on the left in a `div` and the `div` will be the flex child whose height is altered instead of the `input`'s. Then you can set the `input`'s width to 100% or whatever else you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

**IMPORTANT**
There is a style called `align-items` which by default is `stretch`. This is what it makes the elements width/height to match it's parents depending on `flex-direction`.

For anyone getting here, this might be useful: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

You must change just "align-items".
I have this **HTML** case:

```
<section>
    <hgroup>
        <h1>Our Products</h1>
        <h3>We build all kind of containers</h3>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing..</p>
    </hgroup>
    <button class="full-color pull-right">View All Products</button>
</section>
```

...and the **CSS** is like that:

```
section {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

**Now input height is same as hgroup**
But, if I add to the section:
`align-items: baseline;`
the input height is like you expected. You must avoid:

```
align-items: inherit/unset/stretch/initial/normal
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
flex-flow: wrap;
```

This way, the height will remain as it. 
`display: flex;` won't affect it

Answer (score -2):

You just need to add flex-flow: wrap-reverse to the flex parent and then everything goes well :)

example:

```
.parent {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  flex-flow: wrap-reverse;
}
```

Good Luck